# How to avoid text wrap when the parent element has position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```
<nav>
  <ul _v-2e9e2f12="">
    <li _v-2e9e2f12="">
      <a _v-2e9e2f12="">
      </a>
      <ul _v-0078ee36="" _v-2e9e2f12="">
        <li>List element</li>
        <li>List element</li>
        <li>List element</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`ul[_v-0078ee36]` has `position: absolute` so the `li` elements inside it have text wrap (no full width).

How to change the CSS so they don't have text wrap and expand the width of their parent?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9jm82cb/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

Force the white space in the child `li`s to not wrap:

```
nav > ul[_v-2e9e2f12] > li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/d9jm82cb/7/